# How to correctly specify Route by: id on two conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

I try to make routes and faced a problem. I want to make transition to different lists of films where in the address what list (/ popular or / upcoming) will be specified, and also on the page about the film and in the address there will be a movie id / /44535).Code which I wrote worked but only when there is one of the routes such as this one.

```
<Route path="/:name" children={<ChooseListFilm />} />
```

As soon as I added a second /: id, everything stopped working. I realized that they somehow interfere with each other but I don’t know how to fix it. Separately, they work But if together then no.Thank you!
Route

```
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/:name" children={<ChooseListFilm />} />
        <Route path="/:id" children={<ChooseFilm />} />
    </Switch>
```

Header

```
<li>
    <Link to="/upcoming">
        Upcoming
    </Link>
</li>
<li>
    <Link to="/popular">
        Popular
    </Link>
</li>
```

Пытаюсь сделать роуты и столкнулся с проблемой.Хочу сделать переход на разные списки фильмов где в адресе будет указан какой это список (/popular или /upcoming), а также на страницу про фильм и в адресе будет id фильма (/44535).Тот код который я написал работал но только когда есть один из роутов например этот

} />
Как только я добавил второй с /:id всё перестал работать.Я понял что они как-то друг другу мешает но не знаю как это исправить.По отдельности они работают Но если вместе тогда нет.Буду рад помощи.Спасибо!

Route

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/:name" children={<ChooseListFilm />} />
    <Route path="/:id" children={<ChooseFilm />} />
</Switch>
```

Header

Upcoming

Popular

ChooseListFilm

```
export default function ChooseListFilm() {
    let {name} = useParams();
  return (
        <ListFilms  
          filmType={name}
        />
  );
}
```

FilmCards

```
// Here I map API and get the film id 
<Link to={`${value.id}`}>
   <h1>{value.title}</h1>
</Link>
```

ChooseFilm

```
export default function ChooseFilm() {
    let {id} = useParams();
  return (
        <About 
            filmId={id}
        />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one route to match both, you can do something like this, with a parent component.

#### Option 1

```
const Chooser = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  if (id === 'upcoming') {
    return <ChooseListFilm />;
  }
  return <ChooseFilm />;
}

<Route path="/:id(upcoming|popular)" children={<Chooser />} />
```

#### Option 2

On the other hand, you can create separate route matchers instead, like this...

```
<Route path="/list/:name" children={<ChooseListFilm />} />
<Route path="/films/:id" children={<ChooseFilm />} />
```

You will then need to update your links e.g.

```
<Link to="/list/upcoming">Upcoming</Link>
<Link to="/films/popular">Popular</Link>
```

Comment: ohh thanks! I tried second option and it works but when i refresh page I have an error like this "localhost: 8080 / film/ main.js net :: ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)". Did you know why this problem appers?

Comment: This is probably an unrelated error. Can you link a screenshot to the error or paste the error stack here?

Comment: I add my code on codepen there you can see the screenshot of error. Thank you! [Link](https://codepen.io/Orest97/pen/YzygPPJ?editors=0010&__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=86b73e7ca8f350c1236e7b1bff6801ed06da7435-1590173843-0-AfgwPW9u7VVAJXeOLvK5rTyIOluuqjW2z9kC84o_UvHeZvr4sAWlFCM3gwzMwFFiehTiqxKRmp84NQEEcRJanOenjYH11KHX2qbOmlelIysXkMm7_Tof6vw_SCPWfjXhzmkdDFj9lSMRyy5DiMKtnNkYJaA8Ak7Ou7h0lT68oV9FdyKqkZC_dKIKc5oc0IlH8g2c6K1N1QWKkoKEG9woGw-JN_417yltjYbn7X1GYlATCOo-Gkg4y6uIV8ozcSOqI2wS5wmSrj82ru0rWXruZ5dgNeAemFBdF04GXPA8AwvrOkc-74koBD-pLK1ajec4gIlBR2EOBIuunSnrA6wrgciEIfwKNGA9_PssDiIXt8OkVoPGuiff0ReXIimJlp5jng)

Comment: if you can, please try to replicate your code/file structure in https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: I replicate my code to codesandbox and strange because there all works right [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-haslett-v8e90?file=/src/App.js), so if you have time i send link to project in githhub. I understand that it's hard to spend a lot of time to my project, so if you don't want to look on it I will understand you) github [link](https://github.com/OrestHaponov/Films)

Comment: Mayby the problem can be at webpack.config?